# Not able to post to wordpress site using the rest api of wordpress

Tags: c#, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using WordpressPCL to create a console app that posts automatically on WordPress. After multiple tries, I'm not able to post, receiving every time the

```
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_create",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

I have been trying with the BasicAuth provided by the WordPressPCL (using application password and simple password), even both JWT Auth plugins (Useful Team & Enrique Chavez).

I have been modifying the `.htcaccess` with the provided lines,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

but still not working, and I'm out of solutions.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I am also trying to do this with C# and the WordPressPCL.  I am having trouble.  Getting the same error.  I did everything that  you did .htcaccess  and I still get the same error Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.  Do you have any more recommendations?

Comment: Hey @wolfeh, have you seen my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved after doing a site Health Check and seeing that the Authorization Header was missing and after following instructions within this link: https://www.wp-pay.org/http-authorization-header-missing/ i had to send an email to the host provider to change the php version to a Fast-CGI one.

Works as expected afterwards.